# Getting Exception: "Read a negative frame size (-2147418110)!" While running hive queries multithreading way

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I've integrate hive, hdfs, sqoop functionality into java & its working fine. But Its executing in **sequential manner**.

So Now I'm trying implement multithreading to improve performance.

This is sample template of my workflow.

1) Main Java class --> calling one DAO class function:(in this method I've write several hive opertation like join on table, group by etc. Then inserting matched result to antoher tables)

2) In that DAO class there  lots steps(Loading data to hdfs, filter out records & insert it into another table etc.) So I figured out some steps which are independent of each other. Then I put this steps into 4 different threads, so that this step will execute in parallel.

3) In this 4 threads I'm calling some functions of other class, which again performaing some different hive queries. So basically I'm performaning some operation on Hive parallely.

**So Here is my quesion**

1) Can we execute Hive queries in multithreading ways?

2) If Yes. then which parameters need to be set in hive-site.xml file?.

3) Can hive handle concurrent JDBC statements?

**This is exception I'm getting**

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2147418110)!
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:262)
    at org.ecl.dao.HadoopDBOperationsDAO.insertNonUTIValueMatchTrades_intoTPCP(HadoopDBOperationsDAO.java:133)
    at org.ecl.service.DTCCService_MultiThreading_Runnable.callHadoopServiceforLoadData(DTCCService_MultiThreading_Runnable.java:133)
    at org.ecl.DTCCHiveClient.main(DTCCHiveClient.java:26)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2147418110)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:426)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:405)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:225)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:212)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:253)
    ... 3 more
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2147418110)!
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:262)
    at org.ecl.dao.DTCCPairingLogicDAO.fieldBreak(DTCCPairingLogicDAO.java:60)
    at org.ecl.thread.FieldBreakThread.run(FieldBreakThread.java:41)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2147418110)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:426)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:405)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:225)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:212)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:253)
    ... 3 more
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: ExecuteStatement failed: out of sequence response
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:262)
    at org.ecl.dao.HadoopDBOperationsDAO.recordswithMatchedUTIValue(HadoopDBOperationsDAO.java:149)
    at org.ecl.thread.UTIValueMatchedThread.run(UTIValueMatchedThread.java:40)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: ExecuteStatement failed: out of sequence response
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:76)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:225)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:212)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:253)
    ... 3 more
0 Trade records
Breaks identified in trade records matching on UTI
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot read. Remote side has closed. Tried to read 3072 bytes, but only got 175 bytes. (This is often indicative of an internal error on the server side. Please check your server logs.)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:262)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:392)
    at org.ecl.dao.DTCCOperationDAO.countRows(DTCCOperationDAO.java:45)
    at org.ecl.thread.FieldBreakThread.run(FieldBreakThread.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot read. Remote side has closed. Tried to read 3072 bytes, but only got 175 bytes. (This is often indicative of an internal error on the server side. Please check your server logs.)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:354)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:215)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:225)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.ExecuteStatement(TCLIService.java:212)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:253)
    ... 4 more
}
```

So Help me to resolve this.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this problem ? I am also facing a similar issue like this :
`org.apache.thrift.TException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!`
Do you know for any solution to this ? Am stuck since a long with this. Am using Cassandra 2.2 db alongwith Play! 2.4 framework and Kundera as an ORM tool for connecting to db. Please help!

Comment: Yes Vinit, can you check the value of hive.exec.parallel parameter in hive-site.XML? If it is false then set this to true to achieve parallelism using below commands. Set hive.exec.parallel = true;

Comment: where can I find hive-site.XML file ? One more thing, I got solved with this issue, I just changed the name of the keyspace, and set the port to 9160 in persistence.xml. The most recent error I encounter is :


`com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryHandlerException: No entity found by the name: Employee
 at com.impetus.kundera.query.KunderaQuery.initEntityClass(KunderaQuery.java:608) ~[kundera-core-3.2.jar:na]
 at com.impetus.kundera.query.KunderaQuery.postParsingInit(KunderaQuery.java:540) ~[kundera-core-3.2.jar:na] .......
 
[error] m.p.EmployeeProcessImpl$ - No entity found by the name: Employee`

Comment: This file is located in under hive/conf directory. If you are using Linux then just search using command "find / -name hive-site.xml" OR you can check value on hive she'll as well by this command "hive> set hive.exec.parallel; it will show you either true OR false. This issue looks different, Please can you ask this question on stakeoverflow with details, so that other people can also help.

Comment: Yes I am using Linux, but the command you wrote, only showed me some permission denied thing for several files. Can you please tell if  you have some idea regarding the exception being thrown at runtime, which I wrote above ? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Try with sudo option I.e  "sudo find / -name hive-site.XML"